# Why does this work in the Python IDLE shell but not when I run it as a Python script from the command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This works in the Python 3.3.2 Shell

## Inside the Python 3.3.2 Shell

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
2013-07-09 19:40:32.532341
```

That's great! I then wrote a simple text file named "datetime.py"

## Inside Datetime.py

```
#Date time
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
#Prints GMT, which is named Universal Coordinated Time
# Which is UTC because in French it's something like
# Universahl Tyme Coordinatay
#Outputs something like 2013-07-09 15:15:19.695531
```

## Proving that the file exists

```
C:\Python33\myscripts>ls
__pycache__  ex1.out  ex2.out  ex3.py    helloworld.py              read1.py
datetime.py  ex1.py   ex2.py   first.py  pythonintoimportexport.py  test.py
```

Here is where it gets mysterious!

```
C:\Python33\myscripts>python datetime.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datetime.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "C:\Python33\myscripts\datetime.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utcnow'
```

## Question

Why does the same code work in the Python Shell, but not when run as a script?

Comment: Try changing your filename to something else.

Comment: *Never* use names of built-ins. This is true for both filenames but also for class/functions/identifier names. As you already experienced not following this advice *will* create problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that file is recursively importing itself, instead of importing the built-in module `datetime`:

**Demo:**

```
$ cat datetime.py
import datetime
print datetime.__file__
$ python datetime.py
/home/monty/py/datetime.pyc
/home/monty/py/datetime.pyc
```

This happens because the [module is searched](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in this order:

- the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
  shell variable PATH).
- the installation-dependent default.

Simply change the name of `datetime.py` to something else.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sukrit Kalra says, don't use `datetime.py` as your file name. Python is getting confused with which `datetime` is which (and is importing itself!). Maybe;

```
 $ mv datetime.py my_datetime.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Never use filenames same as module names. Change filename to something else apart from `datetime.py` .

Answer (score 0):

Naming your file `datetime` causes Python to import the file you're running as a module. For example, look at `sys.path`. Mine, for example, is `['', '/usr/lib/python3.3', ...]`, which means that Python looks FIRST in the current working directory (the `''`) for modules. And because anything that ends in .py can be imported as a module, it imports the script that you're actually running (which, if I'm not mistaken, actually causes it to be run twice, once as `__main__` and once as a module).