# python code works fine on python shell but not through cmd when importing py2neo

Tags: python, windows, cmd, py2neo

as said in the title I'm having problem runnig my code from cmd which is working just fine in python shell.

I have py2neo version 4.

here is my code:

```
from py2neo import Graph
print ("passed")
```

here is the output from python shell:

```
passed
>>>
```

here is the output from cmd command:

```
D:\py2neo>python py2neo.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py2neo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from py2neo import Graph
  File "D:\ALI\Desktop\ayten\mine-py2neo\py2neo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from py2neo import Graph
ImportError: cannot import name 'Graph'
```

I've been searching, the answer out there were the different versions of python that I have on my system, which has cause this problem. But I checked that out and realized that both of them have the same version.

here is how i figured out the versions:

opening the python shell:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>>
```

in cmd:

```
D:\py2neo>python --version
Python 3.6.4

D:\py2neo>python
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you call your test program `py2neo.py` ? if so, just rename it.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre damnit, you beat me to it. go ahead and make this an answer, the terminal output tells you the filename is the problem :)

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure that this is worth / not already a duplicate: found it, with csv module.

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre one quick search later, it is technically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557168/, which also has a much better explanation than i could ever give.
edit: didn't catch you marking it. i'll leave this here as alternative explanation.

Comment: added as duplicate target thanks

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes it's exactly that. I did as you said, and now it's working just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that py2neo is installed?  What happens if you run `pip install py2neo`?  I've had issues with `pip` and `python` versions in the past, so I would make sure that your `pip` is the same version as your `python` by running `pip --version`

Comment: thank you for answering, but this was not the problem. this was about the naming of the python file.